# How many 7 digit numbers can be formed using numbers: $0,0,0,7,7,8,9$

Tags: combinatorics

The number cant start with $0$. So what I thought is that for the first number I have 4 options (Cant be 0), then I have 6 options since I used one digit, then 5 and so on until 1.

That means my result is: $4*6*5*4*3*2*1 = 2880$

Is this correct or not? I really need help figuring out how to take away all options that start with 0. Since I know that usually the result would be $7^7$.

Comment: Don’t forget that some of the digits occur repeatedly.  Permuting identical symbols doesn’t change the number, so they will be a factor you have to divide by.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $3$ spots from $6$ for the $0$'s, then pick $2$ from the remaining $4$ for the $7$'s, then $1$ rom the remaining $2$ for the $8$. By multiplication principle, you have

$C(6,3)C(4,2)C(2,1)C(1,1) = 20*6*2*1 = 240$.

Answer (score 0):

So the number of all strings is $${7!\over 3!\cdot 2!}$$

the number of bad string are the one wich starts with $0$, that is $${6!\over 2!\cdot 2!}$$ so...

Comment: An answer with no explanation.  Students can usually get the same from their solution manuals.

Comment: @Aqua Oops, for some reason my head kept on telling me that numbers can repeat instead of using the numbers I have. I foolishly didn't even see I have so many 0's and 7's. Thank you, it is clear now!

Answer (score 0):

$0,0,0,7,7,8,9$

Since the number mustn't begin with $' 0 '$, it can either begin with $7,8,9$

So we can rearrange the numbers, an example $7,0,0,0,7,8,9$

Normally any of the $7$ numbers will occur at the beginning in $(7-1)!$ ways

There are two $7$ there, but will count it as one because their position in the permutation are symmetric and would result in the same value

Therefore the number of seven-digit can can be formed are $3×6!$

$2,160$